# Dejar de guardar datos en arreglos

Tags: java

que tal, soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y tengo el siguiente problemita. "Hacer un programa en Java que lea un vector de 10 posiciones
y realice, mediante un menú, las siguientes opciones:"
Ya tengo listo todo para guardar los datos que ingrese el usuario, necesito saber como dejar de pedir datos (Pide muchisimos datos, mas de los 10) y se despliegue el menú de opciones, les agradezco cualquier ayuda. Aqui les  dejo para que miren:

```
package ejercicioclase;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author USUARIO
 */
public class EjercicioClase {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        float numeros [] = new float [10];
        int opcion = 0;

         System.out.println("Lectura de los elementos del array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print("numeros[" + i + "]= ");
            numeros[i] = entrada.nextInt();
            }


        opcion =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la operación que desea realizar:\n"
        + "1. Lectura del vector\n"
        + "2. Impresión inversa\n"
        + "3. Imprimir valores primos\n"
        + "4. Imprimir posiciones pares\n"
        + "5. Imprimir la suma de todos los elementos del vector\n"
        + "6. Imprimir el promedio del vector\n"
        + "7. Imprimir los valores pares elevados al cuadrado\n"
        + "8. Imprimir los valores impares aplicando raiz cuadrada\n"
        + "9. Vector ordenado\n"
        + "10. Salir."));

        switch(opcion){
            case 1: 
             System.out.println("/n Imprimir los elementos del arreglo: ");
        for(float i:numeros){
            System.out.println(i);     
        }
         break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Imprimiendo elementos del arreglo de forma inversa: ");
                for(int i=9; i>=0; i--){
                    System.out.print("  " +numeros[i]);
                }
        break;
            case 3:
```

Answer (score 0):

estaba revisando tu  post el cual falta parte del código y en la siguiente parte:

```
 System.out.println("Lectura de los elementos del array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("numeros[" + i + "]= ");
        numeros[i] = entrada.nextInt();
        }
```

Yo le agregaría un if de la siguiente forma dentro de ese for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i>10){

    //Aquí debería ir el break, o exit que quieras usar.

    }else{System.out.print("numeros[" + i + "]= "); numeros[i] = entrada.nextInt();

    }}
```

Ahora si quieres, puedes postear el código completo para obtener una ayuda mas personalizada.

Answer (score 0):

Algo que note en tu codigo es que despues del for estaria bueno poner el resto del codigo dentro de un while, esto para que luego del for se quede la ejecucion dentro del while, puedes intentarlo de esta manera...

```
while(opcion != 10){

opcion =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la operación que desea realizar:\n"
        + "1. Lectura del vector\n"
        + "2. Impresión inversa\n"
        + "3. Imprimir valores primos\n"
        + "4. Imprimir posiciones pares\n"
        + "5. Imprimir la suma de todos los elementos del vector\n"
        + "6. Imprimir el promedio del vector\n"
        + "7. Imprimir los valores pares elevados al cuadrado\n"
        + "8. Imprimir los valores impares aplicando raiz cuadrada\n"
        + "9. Vector ordenado\n"
        + "10. Salir."));
```